# Query inserting multiple times using cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'have the below result for cursor

```
PONumber  Code   QuantityReceived 
0200073 200757  4
0200073 201052  2
0200073 201435  2
0200073 200757  10
0200073 201056  1
0200073 202200  2
```

the procedure I'm using is

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @PN nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @TCODE nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @REQNTY INT;
DECLARE @LOTID nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @QUANTITY nvarchar(50);

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT PONumber,Code,QuantityReceived 
FROM Temp_stock2 
--GROUP BY PONumber,Code,QuantityReceived

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @PN,@TCODE,@REQNTY
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
    BEGIN
        WHILE(@REQNTY>0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP(1)@LOTID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID,@QUANTITY=RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity
            FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
            INNER JOIN  Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID
            WHERE  RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity>0 AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode
            ORDER BY RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity DESC;

            IF (@QUANTITY >= @REQNTY)
                BEGIN
                    -- UPDATING  LOT ENTRY TABLE
                    UPDATE [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
                    SET RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity = RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity-@REQNTY,LastUpdated=GETDATE()
                    FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
                    INNER JOIN   Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID 
                    WHERE RR1038_LotEntry.ID =@LOTID AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode;

                    -- INSERTING THE SAME DATA TO LOT HISTORY TABLE
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].RR1038_LotHistory 
                    (StoreID,LotEntryId,Quantity,ReferenceNumber,ReferenceType,LastUpdated)
                    SELECT 
                    0 as StoreID ,Temp_stock2.LotID,
                    @REQNTY,
                    Temp_stock2.PurchaseOrderid  as ReferenceNumber,
                    3 as ReferenceType,GETDATE() as LastUpdated
                    FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
                    INNER JOIN   Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID 
                    WHERE RR1038_LotEntry.ID =@LOTID AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode;

                    SET @REQNTY=0;

                END 
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    -- INSERTING THE SAME DATA TO LOT HISTORY TABLE
                    INSERT INTO [dbo].RR1038_LotHistory 
                    (StoreID,LotEntryId,Quantity,ReferenceNumber,ReferenceType,LastUpdated)
                    SELECT 
                    0 as StoreID ,Temp_stock2.LotID,
                    @REQNTY,
                    Temp_stock2.PurchaseOrderid  as ReferenceNumber,
                    3 as ReferenceType,GETDATE() as LastUpdated
                    FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
                    INNER JOIN   Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID 
                    WHERE RR1038_LotEntry.ID =@LOTID AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode;

                    SET @REQNTY=@REQNTY-@QUANTITY;

                    -- UPDATING  LOT ENTRY TABLE
                    UPDATE [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
                    SET RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity = 0,LastUpdated=GETDATE()
                    FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
                    INNER JOIN Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID 
                    WHERE RR1038_LotEntry.ID =@LOTID AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode;
                END
        END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @PN,@TCODE,@REQNTY
END
    CLOSE CUR 
    DEALLOCATE CUR
END
```

While I'm executing the procedure I'm getting duplicate insertion for a specific row for the CODE exists twice.

[image: Output]
how can I avoid the duplicate entry in the result set?

Comment: They're not duplicate when the values are different (date and the value in the middle)

Comment: Do you find any problem with procedure?

Comment: Yes you were correct, I was blindly searching in the lot table, without providing any specific inputs, changed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some modification in the query as below, now working fine,

```
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT PONumber,Code,QuantityReceived ,LotID
FROM Temp_stock2 


OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @PN,@TCODE,@REQNTY,@LOTID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
BEGIN

    -- UPDATING  LOT ENTRY TABLE
    UPDATE [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
    SET RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity = RR1038_LotEntry.Quantity-@REQNTY,LastUpdated=GETDATE()
    FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
    INNER JOIN   Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID 
    WHERE RR1038_LotEntry.ID =@LOTID AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode;

    -- INSERTING THE SAME DATA TO LOT HISTORY TABLE
    INSERT INTO [dbo].RR1038_LotHistory 
    (StoreID,LotEntryId,Quantity,ReferenceNumber,ReferenceType,LastUpdated)
    SELECT 
    0 as StoreID ,Temp_stock2.LotID,
    @REQNTY,
    Temp_stock2.PurchaseOrderid  as ReferenceNumber,
    3 as ReferenceType,GETDATE() as LastUpdated
    FROM [dbo].RR1038_LotEntry
    INNER JOIN   Temp_stock2 on Temp_stock2.LotID=RR1038_LotEntry.ID 
    WHERE RR1038_LotEntry.ID =@LOTID AND Temp_stock2.Code=@TCode;
END

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @PN,@TCODE,@REQNTY,@LOTID
END
CLOSE CUR 
DEALLOCATE CUR
```